# Weird table's data in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

I have a table in my database called `notifications`, data will be inserted into this table whenever notifications arrive from other users in my application. The table's schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[notifications](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [sender] [char](17) NULL,
    [reciever] [char](17) NULL,
    [letter_code] [char](15) NULL,
    [txt] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [dateandtime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [letter_kind] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [seen] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_notifications] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

the inserted row must be something like this:

```
id    || sender   ||    reciever || letter_code || txt     ||  dateandtime          || letter_kind ||   seen
============================================================================================================
1     ||   2      ||    2        ||    1734     || message ||   2015-10-12 09:59:01 ||   PS        || flase
```

today I was checking my database's tables, and I noticed something strange has happened. Some strange data are inserted into the `notification` table:

[image]

As you can see the `txt` column contains a very strange value:

```
1<div style="display:none">looking to cheat <a href="http://blog.perecruit.com/template/page/reason-women-cheat.aspx">go</a> how many men have affairs</div>
```

And other columns contain `1` !
Any idea?

PS: I'm sure in only one place data for this table will be written:

```
context.InsTotNotification(WebContext.Current.User.UserCode, CheckedUsersForSend.ElementAt(j), LetCods.ElementAt(i),
                                        string.Format("letter kind {0} letter code {1} datetime.",
                                        LetterKind, Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(LetCods.ElementAt(i).Substring(4, 11)), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), DateTime.Now, LetterKind);
```

**Update**: There's no form for allowing users to input the data, data will be written using the backend not users.

**Update 2**: I'm using EntityFramework Database First and `InsTotNotification` is a stored procedure inside my context:

```
    [Invoke]
    public string InsTotNotification(string sender, string reciever,string letter_code,string Txt,DateTime dateandtime,string Letter_kind)
    {
        var MQuery = ObjectContext.InsTo_Notification(sender, reciever, letter_code, Txt, dateandtime, Letter_kind).FirstOrDefault();
        return "Ok";
    }
```

And here's the sp:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsTo_Notification]
@Sender char(17), 
@Reciever char(17), 
@Letter_code char(15), 
@Txt nvarchar(MAX), 
@DateandTime datetime2, 
@Letter_kind nvarchar(50)
AS

BEGIN TRANSACTION InsertNotifications
Declare @T1 int
INSERT notifications (sender, reciever, letter_code, txt, dateandtime, letter_kind) 
       values (@Sender, @Reciever, @Letter_code, @Txt, @DateandTime,@Letter_kind)
SELECT @T1=@@ERROR
--------------------------
if (@T1=0)
BEGIN
COMMIT TRANSACTION InsertNotifications
SELECT @Letter_code as LetterNo
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION InsertNotifications
  SELECT 'NO' as 'It has Problem'
 END
```

**Update 3**: There's also these types of rows in the table:

[image]

Notice that the text `نامه PS به شماره 11968 به شما ارجاع داده شد` in the selected row is the actual value for `txt` field.

Comment: Why most of the datatype are char or varchar but you only have 1? This is probably a problem somewhere in the code, not SQL Server. If you only store number, you should not use char type. They won't fail if you try to insert text.

Comment: Looks like someone populating hidden parts of the form with malicious HTML. Check that only you can write into variables feeding these column.

Comment: I can't exactly see, what part of your code is responsible for writing `txt` field content. Apparently some SQL injection is possible.

Comment: @Arvo This table is something like a log table for user's notifications, it means that, there's no form or something like that for inserting data.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi how do you populate it? and how do you create the "message" or "txt column"? it is possible that the problem stems from there depending on how the txt column is populated.

Comment: There can be some other form for data entry, which is prone to attack. Successful SQL injection is not limited to tables, included in update satements :) Look over the code, how are your form entries written into database - do you use stored procedures with parameters (good) or string concatenation (bad) or similar? What I meant by my previous comment - I can't understand, which parameter of your `InsTotNotification` method is responsible for filling `txt` field?

Comment: @Arvo I have updated my question.

Comment: It is likely that someone has update rights in SQL server updates the value

Comment: @SirwanAfifi  if I get it correct you have at first "letter kind......" in txt and then it becomes 1? where?

Comment: Same question here - how can `txt` field contain value `1`? There must be another code path, allowing to update this field. Or there was some SQL attack and attacker could update `txt` field only - but then new records should contain correct text. If new records contain also `1`, then you can use SQL Profiler (with sp statements logging turned on) to find wrong code.

Comment: It looks a lot like someone has found some sort of web service that EF may have exposed for your stored proc to get called from client side code. I'd take a look at what you're exposing to the client, and the security on it.

Comment: Maybe the database is exposed to the internet at the network level?

Comment: Specifically looks like http://www.abuseipdb.com/report-history/206.72.117.72. May be from another database even on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

definitely SQL Injection...
Is this coming from a Web application or something that can be reahed by the web, right?
Your stored procedure takes any char inputs without proper validation.
Try to check if parameters contain "<", ">", reserved SQL Server terms/statements or other unwanted chars.